# JQ grid Date format(Month date, year) Ex- June 26, 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Am using JQ a grid the date format which I get this (yyyy-mm-dd) format. I want to change the date format to be mm date, year.

Example: June 26, 2015

If my input date format is null then I want to show dots(...)

Grid data should be like this,

Task Date

June 26, 2015
...

July 26, 2015

Answer (score 0):

Use moment and specify the format.

```
var dateString = '1995-12-25', formatted = '...'; 

if (dateString) {
   formatted = moment(dateString).fomat('MM DD, YYYY');
}
```

Then inject the formatted  string wherever required.

More on formats - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/